# How to fix slicing a list inside?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a categorical dataset and I implement the `LabelEncoder` to change it in numerical and then I implemented the `StandardScaler()` function to change it in 2D. Now I want to use the SVM Kernel function to separate the data in 3D. It gives me error in `X0_org`, `Y0_orig` and `X1_orig`, `Y1_orig`. The error is too many indices ...

```py
def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax-vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

def fn_kernel(x1, x2):
    """ Implements a kernel phi(x1,y1) = [x1, y1, x1^2 + y1^2] """
    return np.array([x1, x2, x1**2.0 + x2**2.0])

""" Generate linearly nonseparable dataset (in R^2) """


# # Read the CSV file
dataset = pd.read_csv('raw_train.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:3].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
df_X = pd.DataFrame(X)
df_y = pd.DataFrame(y)

#  Encoding categorical data
le = LabelEncoder()
X_encode = df_X.apply(le.fit_transform)
# print(X)
y_encode = df_y.apply(le.fit_transform)
# print(y)

# splitting the datset into the training set and test set.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_encode, y_encode,test_size=0.34, random_state=0)

# Changed the data in 2D
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_s = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
Y_s = sc_X.transform(X_test)

X = np.array(X_s)
Y = np.array(Y_s)
print(X)
print()
print(Y)


A = X[np.where(Y <= 0)]
B = X[np.where(Y >= 1)]
print(A)
print()
print(B)


X0_orig = A[:, 0]
Y0_orig = A[:, 1]
print(X0_orig)

X1_orig = B[:, 0]
Y1_orig = B[:, 1]

frac0 = len(np.where(Y == 0)[0]) / float(len(Y))
frac1 = len(np.where(Y == 1)[0]) / float(len(Y))

print("Percentage of '0' labels:", frac0)
print("Percentage of '1' labels:", frac1)

A = np.array([fn_kernel(x, y) for x, y in zip(np.ravel(X0_orig), np.ravel(Y0_orig))])
X0 = A[:, 0]
Y0 = A[:, 1]
Z0 = A[:, 2]

A = np.array([fn_kernel(x, y) for x, y in zip(np.ravel(X1_orig), np.ravel(Y1_orig))])
X1 = A[:, 0]
Y1 = A[:, 1]
Z1 = A[:, 2]


def plot_no_decision_boundary():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')

    ax.scatter(X0, Y0, Z0, c='r', marker='o')
    ax.scatter(X1, Y1, Z1, c='b', marker='^')

    ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
    ax.set_title("Data in R^3 (separable)")

    # Project data to X/Y plane
    ax2d = fig.add_subplot(121)
    ax2d.scatter(X0, Y0, c='r', marker='o')
    ax2d.scatter(X1, Y1, c='b', marker='^')

    ax2d.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax2d.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax2d.set_title("Data projected to R^2 (nonseparable)")

    plt.show()


def plot_decision_boundary():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')

    ax.scatter(X0, Y0, Z0, c='r', marker='o')
    ax.scatter(X1, Y1, Z1, c='b', marker='^')

    ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
    ax.set_title("Data in R^3 (separable w/ hyperplane)")

    x = np.arange(-1.25, 1.25, 0.1)
    y = np.arange(-1.25, 1.25, 0.1)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    Z = np.zeros(X.shape)
    Z[:, :] = 0.5

    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='#09F911')

    # Project data to X/Y plane
    ax2d = fig.add_subplot(122)
    ax2d.scatter(X0, Y0, c='r', marker='o')
    ax2d.scatter(X1, Y1, c='b', marker='^')

    ax2d.add_patch(pl.Circle((0, 0), radius=sqrt(0.5), fill=False, linestyle='solid', linewidth=4.0, color='black'))
    ax2d.add_patch(pl.Circle((0, 0), radius=sqrt(0.5), fill=False, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.5, color='#09F911'))

    ax2d.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax2d.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax2d.set_title("Data projected to R^2 (hyperplane projection shown)")

    plt.show()


def main():
    print("...Projecting dataset to R^3 (no decision boundary)...")
    plot_no_decision_boundary()
    print("...Projecting dataset to R^3 (with decision boundary)...")
    plot_decision_boundary()
    print("...Done.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I print the `A` and `B`, it gives me this output.

```
A: [-0.03689752 -0.84216039 -0.27461752 -0.84216039 -0.17987541 -0.84216039
-1.4666764  -0.84216039  1.32139242  1.14423966  0.53501403 -0.84216039
0.24905826 -0.84216039 -1.10923168 -0.75178696 -0.68029802  1.99555397
1.10692559 -0.84216039 -0.84216039 -0.3228533   1.24990347  1.03543664]

B: [ 1.14423966  0.00915392 -0.84216039  1.14423966  0.57669679 -0.84216039]
```

But if I print `X0_orig` or `X1_orig`, it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
X0_orig = A[:, 0]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: `A` is one dimensional... so `A[:, 0]` doesn't make sense as a slice... What is it you're trying to do there? If it's just taking the first element - then use `A[0]`

Comment: `A` is not one dimensional, You can see the output of `print(A)` which is 2D. I want to store the first column of `A` in `X0_orig` and the second column `Y0_orig`.

Comment: `A` as you've shown it here definitely looks 1D... and the error you're getting is what'd happen trying to apply that slice to a 1D array... what does `A.shape` say?

Comment: Unless you pasted the wrong output, print(A) is 1D (one pair of brackets)

Comment: If I print the `X=np.array(X_s)` it gives me in 2D. Further, `StandardScalar()` changed it into 2D.

Comment: In `A = np.array([fn_kernel(x, y) for x, y in zip(np.ravel(X0_orig), np.ravel(Y0_orig))])` you're making an array from a list... what does `fn_kernel` return? If it returns a scalar then you'll definitely have a 1D array... if it returns lists, then yes, you should get a 2D array for instance... but otherwise... Everything is telling you that `A` after that command is 1D

Comment: Yes, you are right, `A` is `1D`, but why `X= np.array(X_s)` is a 2D, `print(X.shape)` give me `(31,2)`, while I used `A`, then it changed to `1D`. How to fix it that `A` should be 2D.

Comment: @Zia look into what `fn_kernel` returns as per my comment above... Looks like it returns a single value which means in the list-comp you're creating a simple Python list - which when passed to `np.array` is 1D...

Comment: Actually, the complete code is not from me, I adjusted for my dataset. but the `fn_kernel` return a scalar. because we have the multiplication of `[x1, x2, x..]`. I think the problem is not with the `fn_kernel`, because I comment all but the problem arises in `X0_orgin`, because `A` here changed to 1D but upper code `X=np.array(X_s)` is a `2D`.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved and the problem was the `np.where` was return `1D` array. Here what I have changed. I used `np.argwhere` and now it gives me in `2D`.

```
A = X_s[np.argwhere(Y_s <= 0)]
B = X_s[np.argwhere(Y_s >= 1)]
print(A.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

`A` and `B` in your case are arrays with one single dimension. Therefore trying to access the first column will result in an error. Only if you can you specify exactly what information are you looking for.

Use `A.shape` to monitor the shape of your array and `A.reshape` if necessary to make it two dimensional

Comment: The problem is if I print X=np.array(X_s), it prints me in 2D. but while I use print(A.shape()) it gives me error that tuple object is not callable, how to fix it.

Comment: `print(A.shape)` -> `(24,)`, but if I print `X=np.array(X_s)`, it gives me `(31,2)`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this line `A = X[np.where(Y <= 0)]` ? @Zia

Comment: I used the `Kernel` to separate the data like the `SVM`.

Comment: I mean what kind of operation, filter X where ... @Zia

Comment: try to use `X_s[np.where(Y_s <= 0)]` ie  `X_s` instead of `X` and `Y_s` instead of `Y`

Comment: I did, it again changes it in 1D.

Comment: try this `X_s[Y_s <= 0]`, and if there is still the same problem; what is the result of `X_s.shape` `Y_s.shape` `X_s[np.where(Y_s <= 0)].shape`. If the first result in an error what is the type of `X_s` and `Y_s` by the command `type(X_s)`

Comment: The output of `print(X_s.shape) => (31,2)` and `print(Y_s.shape) => (17,2)` and the `print(type(X_s) => <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Further the `A= X_s[np.where(Y_s <=0)].shape` give as output `(24,)`.

Comment: The `print(type(A))` give as `<class 'tuple'>`. I don't know why it changes the type?

Comment: I changed the `A` as `A= X_s[np.where(Y_s <= 0)] + 1` and now the type is change to `print(type(A)) => <class 'numpy.ndarray'>` but when I `print(A.shape)`, it gives me again `(24,)`, which is `1D`.